# Vertically align badges with css

Tags: html, css

I have a list which shows a users score.

[image: Align]

This is my HTML. I would like each value to be aligned. I have tried different options such as using tables, and using grid. I am unable to implement it that way. The badges is never aligned. I could finally achieve it though `absolute` positioning of credits. But thats not responsive.

```
    <div class="inner-counter">
      <div class="profile-credits">
        <span  class="credit">{{auth.user?.hdc}}</span>
        <span >
          <div class="badges" style="background-color: #ffcc00"></div>
        </span>
        <span class="counter-text">
          Books hunted
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="profile-credits">
        <span class="credit">{{auth.user?.ohc}}</span>
        <span>
          <div class="badges" style="background-color: #ABBBC2"></div>
        </span>
        <span class="counter-text">
          Own hunts
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="profile-credits">
        <span class="credit">{{auth.user?.hgc}}</span>
        <span>
          <div class="badges" style="background-color: #cc9966"></div>
        </span>
        <span class="counter-text">
          Books hunting
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the css with absolute positioning.

```
  .badges{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 4px;
  }
  .counters{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 15%;
  }
  .counter-text {
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  .profile-credits{
    padding-top: 10px;
    .credit{
      text-align: right;
      position: absolute;
      right: 70%;
    }
  }
  .inner-counter{
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

How can I do it **without absolute positioning of credit**. Each column left-aligned itself?

Comment: • Sometimes if they are inline bullets you can just use the UTF-8 bullet it will be aligned correctly to the text, you only need to make the font bigger. code: `&#8226;` •

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/RemyaJ/n19hdzs6/4/

```
    .inner-counter {
      display:table;
      }
      .profile-credits {
        display:table-row;
      }
    }
    .badge-wrap {
      display: table-cell;
    }
    .badges{
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 4px;
  }
  .counters{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 15%;
  }
  .counter-text {
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: table-cell;
  }
  .profile-credits{
    padding-top: 10px;

  }
  .credit{
      text-align: right;
     display: table-cell;
    }
  .inner-counter{
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically you have to set the width of the `credit`-class to your desired width.

Here's a working version:

https://codepen.io/selbekk/pen/xdrRNp

Another approach is by using either `css-grid` or `flexbox`, but this would be the quickest win (given that you know how large this credits number can be).

Here's how you do the same thing with `flexbox`: https://codepen.io/selbekk/pen/rmwjOz

Comment: if you add more digits this will push the badges as well the text

Comment: Yeah I noticed that as well. Perhaps a grid solution would be the best - given the same HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

There are not aligned because your numbers may grow and push the badges.
You will need to have your number cells growing all together.

You can also review your presentation and put the number at the end instead. this way you have no more issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing that best way is to put the numbers inside container and the badges with the text inside another container, so that each time the number get bigger this will push the whole container and it will be always aligned like this

[image]